# How to split a string by a delimiter in Golang

Tags: go, split

I want to split a string by a delimiter, and the result should be a slice.

For example:

The given string might be like this:

```golang
 foo := "foo=1&bar=2&&a=8"
```

The result should be like

```golang
 result := []string{
    "foo=1",
    "bar=2&",
    "a=8"
}
```

I mean i can use `strings.split(foo, "&")` to split but the result does not meet my requirements.

```golang
 // the result with strings.split()
 result := []string{
    "foo=1",
    "bar=2",
    "",
    "a=8"
}
```

Comment: if you really want `bar=2&` - the character `&` would need to be escaped before processing since it matches the delimiter. In a URL query it would be represented as `%26`

Comment: As mentioned by @colm.anseo, the task you want to solve usually doesn't exist. If the separator character can be part of the data, it must be escaped. Else it isn't even obvious where it should belong: it could be parsed either as `bar=2&` + `a=8` or `bar=2` + `&a=8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [url.ParseQuery](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#ParseQuery). If you need a special characters like `&` (which is the delimiter) to not be treated as such, then it needs to be escaped (`%26`):

```
//m, err := url.ParseQuery("foo=1&bar=2&&a=8")
m, err := url.ParseQuery("foo=1&bar=2%26&a=8") // escape bar's & as %26


fmt.Println(m) // map[a:[8] bar:[2&] foo:[1]]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/zG3NEL70HxE

---

You would typically URL encode parameters like so:

```
q := url.Values{}

q.Add("foo", "1")
q.Add("bar", "2&")
q.Add("a", "8")

fmt.Println(q.Encode()) // a=8&bar=2%26&foo=1
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hSdiLtgVj7m

Comment: Actually, the result still does not meet my requirements. The value of the key 'bar' should be '2&', not just '2' only.

Comment: Updated answer for clarity on how url encoding, escaping & parsing works,